# tmux - Insert a window at a specified position

Tags: tmux

tmux has the "move-window" command with which you can move a window to a specified *empty* index like so:

```
move-window -t 3
```

However, if index 3 is already taken you will not be able to move your current window to position 3.

I'm looking for an option that will allow me to move (insert) my window at position 3 even if it is already taken and then increase the window numbers for the other subsequent windows (for example the one that was originally at 3 will now be 4, the following will be 5 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below will allow you to do what you want. You can run it from a shell prompt or you can do:

```
:run "ins-move 2 5"
```

That example moves window two to the position before window five.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=$1; i<$2-1; i++))
do
    tmux swap-window -s :$i -t :$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great - though I will have to adapt it to work even for cases like "5 2". At least now I know how it's done.

Comment: @Andrei: I'm glad I was able to get you started. Please don't forget to mark answers accepted and to upvote when you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: I upvoted your answer just now. Couldn't do it before because I just now got enough reputation points.

Answer (score 44):

Try: `new-window -a`

using -a option when create new window can insert the new one just at the next index, while all other subsequent windows' index will increase automatically.

Comment: Looks like a better solution than @DennisWilliamson , sorry Dennis :-) I'm running `tmux 1.9a`, maybe this feature wasn't available in previous versions.

Comment: Awesome. Not sure how I missed that. You saved me from 4 years in the past, time traveler! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work if you want a new window at index 0.

Answer (score 6):

At least in tmux 3.2a, you can simply run the OP's command with `-a`:

```
move-window -a -t 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got a solution without the need of external scripts. Put the following in your .tmux.conf:

```
bind i command-prompt -p 'Insert window at:' 'run-shell "if tmux select-window -t %1; then tmux new-window -a; tmux swap-window -s %1 -t \$((%1+1)); else tmux new-window; tmux move-window -t %1; fi; tmux select-window -t #I; tmux select-window -t %1;"'
```

Press [PREFIX]-i and provide wanted insert location. The last 2 select-window commands make sure the 'previous' window is set as expected and you go to the inserted window.

**EDIT:** ok, I spoke too soon. I had to change `#I` to `#{window_id}` because the window index changes for some windows on insertion. The new function (with added newlines for readability):

```
bind i command-prompt -p 'Insert window at:' '      \
    run-shell "                                     \
        if tmux select-window -t %1; then           \
            tmux new-window -a;                     \
            tmux swap-window -s %1 -t \$((%1+1));   \
        else                                        \
            tmux new-window;                        \
            tmux move-window -t %1;                 \
        fi;                                         \
        tmux select-window -t #{window_id};         \
        tmux select-window -t %1;                   \
    "'
```

---

I started using a simplified version, through the following 2 commands in .tmux.conf:

```
 bind i command-prompt -p 'Insert window at:' 'new-window -a -t %1; swap-window -t -1'
 bind I command-prompt -p 'New window at:'    'new-window -t %1'
```

Prefix-i inserts a new window at position *x* when window *x* exists, and moves windows above that one up. Prefix-I creates a new window at position *x* when window *x* doesn't exist.